# Is my Japanese Maple dying?

Tags: japanese-maple

Is this Japanese Maple dying?
Or is this is natural because fall is coming?
Located in California.

[image: stressed Japanese maple]

[image: stressed Japanese maple 2]

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about the plant and its environment ? Is it newly planted or established? How were temperature and water supply? Anything else that may be a factor? I see damage on the leaf margins, which indicates that _something_ is going on, but there’s a wide range of other options between “it’s just fall” and “it’s dying”. And California is a large state with quite different climates….